# Issue with dynamic price value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created the script of automatic add of price when selecting values. It's working and remove field is working but only for "li" string values.
How I can do it, that connect "li" to price and when pressing delete button it counting correct price.
For example, If I will add few elements, and will try to remove first one, it will remove the correct object, but price will deduct from last one. How fix it? thanks

Issue is inside

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <p class="control-label col-xs-4">Ingridients</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="coffee" name="coffee" checked>
                <label for="coffee">Coffee</label>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="gym" name="gym">
                <label for="gym">Gym</label>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="rose" name="rose">
                <label for="rose">Rose</label>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <select name="oil" id="oil">
        <option value="avokado">Avokado</option>
        <option value="kokos">Kokos</option>
        <option value="vine">Vine</option>
    </select>
    </br>

    <select name="color" id="color">
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="pink">pink</option>
    </select>
    </br>

    <select name="smell" id="smell">
        <option value="rose">rose</option>
        <option value="kokos">Kokos</option>
        <option value="gym">gym</option>
    </select>
    </br>

    <button class="btn" style="float:right" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Add</button>

    <ul id="myList">

    </ul>
    <p id="price">Price : 0 pln</p>

    <script>
        var idtext = 0
        var varprice = 0;
        var dict = {};

        function myFunction() {

            var checkboxvalue = 0;
            var node = document.createElement("LI");

            var checkBoxCoffe = document.getElementById("coffee");
            var checkBoxGym = document.getElementById("gym");
            var checkBoxRose = document.getElementById("rose");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode("");

            var selectBoxOil = document.getElementById("oil");
            var strOil = selectBoxOil.options[selectBoxOil.selectedIndex].text;

            var selectBoxColor = document.getElementById("color");
            var strColor = selectBoxColor.options[selectBoxColor.selectedIndex].text;

            var selectBoxSmell = document.getElementById("smell");
            var strSmell = selectBoxSmell.options[selectBoxSmell.selectedIndex].text;

            if (checkBoxCoffe.checked == true) {
                textnode.textContent = textnode.textContent + "Coffee; "
                checkboxvalue = checkboxvalue + 1;
            }
            if (checkBoxGym.checked == true) {
                textnode.textContent = textnode.textContent + "Gym; "
                checkboxvalue = checkboxvalue + 1;
            }
            if (checkBoxRose.checked == true) {
                textnode.textContent = textnode.textContent + "Rose; "
                checkboxvalue = checkboxvalue + 1;
            }
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "Remove";

            button.onclick = function() {

                button.parentElement.remove()

                varprice = varprice - dict[idtext];
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = 'Price : ' + varprice + ' pln';
                return;
            };

            idtext = idtext + 1
            if (checkboxvalue == 1) {
                dict[idtext] = 5;
            } else if (checkboxvalue == 2) {
                dict[idtext] = 7;
            } else if (checkboxvalue == 3) {
                dict[idtext] = 9;
            }
            varprice = varprice + dict[idtext];
            textnode.id = idtext

            textnode.textContent = "Bomb : \n" + strColor + "; " + strOil + " oil; " + "Smell: " + strSmell + " Ingridients : " + textnode.textContent + idtext + "value " + dict[idtext]

            node.appendChild(textnode);
            node.appendChild(button);
            document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = 'Price : ' + varprice + ' pln';

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

cause it's removing only parent object. How connect it to the price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After
`textnode.id = idtext` add `node.id = idtext`

Change
`varprice = varprice - dict[idtext];` after `button.parentElement.remove()`
to `varprice = varprice - dict[button.parentElement.id];`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <p class="control-label col-xs-4">Ingridients</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="coffee" name="coffee" checked>
                <label for="coffee">Coffee</label>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="gym" name="gym">
                <label for="gym">Gym</label>
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="rose" name="rose">
                <label for="rose">Rose</label>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <select name="oil" id="oil">
        <option value="avokado">Avokado</option>
        <option value="kokos">Kokos</option>
        <option value="vine">Vine</option>
    </select>
    </br>

    <select name="color" id="color">
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="pink">pink</option>
    </select>
    </br>

    <select name="smell" id="smell">
        <option value="rose">rose</option>
        <option value="kokos">Kokos</option>
        <option value="gym">gym</option>
    </select>
    </br>

    <button class="btn" style="float:right" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Add</button>

    <ul id="myList">

    </ul>
    <p id="price">Price : 0 pln</p>

    <script>
        var idtext = 0
        var varprice = 0;
        var dict = {};

        function myFunction() {

            var checkboxvalue = 0;
            var node = document.createElement("LI");

            var checkBoxCoffe = document.getElementById("coffee");
            var checkBoxGym = document.getElementById("gym");
            var checkBoxRose = document.getElementById("rose");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode("");

            var selectBoxOil = document.getElementById("oil");
            var strOil = selectBoxOil.options[selectBoxOil.selectedIndex].text;

            var selectBoxColor = document.getElementById("color");
            var strColor = selectBoxColor.options[selectBoxColor.selectedIndex].text;

            var selectBoxSmell = document.getElementById("smell");
            var strSmell = selectBoxSmell.options[selectBoxSmell.selectedIndex].text;

            if (checkBoxCoffe.checked == true) {
                textnode.textContent = textnode.textContent + "Coffee; "
                checkboxvalue = checkboxvalue + 1;
            }
            if (checkBoxGym.checked == true) {
                textnode.textContent = textnode.textContent + "Gym; "
                checkboxvalue = checkboxvalue + 1;
            }
            if (checkBoxRose.checked == true) {
                textnode.textContent = textnode.textContent + "Rose; "
                checkboxvalue = checkboxvalue + 1;
            }
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "Remove";

            button.onclick = function() {

                button.parentElement.remove()
                varprice = varprice - dict[button.parentElement.id];
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = 'Price : ' + varprice + ' pln';
                return;
            };

            idtext = idtext + 1
            if (checkboxvalue == 1) {
                dict[idtext] = 5;
            } else if (checkboxvalue == 2) {
                dict[idtext] = 7;
            } else if (checkboxvalue == 3) {
                dict[idtext] = 9;
            }
            varprice = varprice + dict[idtext];
            textnode.id = idtext
            node.id = idtext

            textnode.textContent = "Bomb : \n" + strColor + "; " + strOil + " oil; " + "Smell: " + strSmell + " Ingridients : " + textnode.textContent + idtext + "value " + dict[idtext]

            node.appendChild(textnode);
            node.appendChild(button);
            document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = 'Price : ' + varprice + ' pln';

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```